# cursor rects on non-key window?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nswindow, nscursor

In short: is there any way to use cursor rects on non-key window, or should I use tracking areas instead?

I want to manually resize window, and making user to first click on it to make key, and only after them show resizing cursors is a bit annoying.

Comment: Option clicking accesses window controls without activating app or window. Feature of OSX.

Comment: This doesn't help to display correct cursor to user while hovering the window without activating it.

Comment: Sure it does. You never said you wanted custom ones. But tracking areas are best for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cursor rects are super-old and inflexible, so you really don’t want to use them anyways—they’d have been deprecated by now except they’re so deep in AppKit.

The new object APIs on `NSTrackingArea` are the way to go.

Comment: But it is worth mentioning that keeping a custom cursor outside a view in your own active app is challenging sometimes as lots of calls are flying around to change cursors all the time from other places.